# Show full virtual keyboard in iPad while using bluetooth scanner

Tags: javascript, ios, bluetooth, keyboard

I am building a web app on Safari for iPad. The problem is while I am using a barcode scanner and I tap on any text input, the virtual keyboard does not expand automatically (see image below).
[image: Keyboard appears compressed]

Now I know that this is because my scanner device is not iOS compatible so it acts as a physical keyboard thus hiding the on screen keyboard.
But is there any way to show the full keyboard programmatically without disconnecting the device?